# Get value from cell without transform in vba macros

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue with vba macros. Cell contains value 941144280284022000000. But when try to get this value in macros, variable is equal 
9.41144280284022E+20. Is it possible to get "real" value?
Thanks.

Comment: You must store that value as Text: Excel can't handle numbers with more than 15 digits of precision.  Is that value intended to be used as a number?

Comment: @TimWilliams  Is it possible to capture the characters as they appear in the **Formula Bar** for the active cell ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
Sub dural()
    MsgBox ActiveCell.Text
End Sub
```

[image]

This will insure that long strings of numerals are not converted to numbers.

**EDIT#1:**

This assumes that the cell actually displays the long string of numerals.  If the cell displays **####**, that is what the sub will pick-up.  If the cell displays **9.41E+20**, then that is what my sub will pick-up.

My sub will **not** necessarily pick-up the contents of the *Formula Bar*.

Comment: But if your column is only wide enough to show `####` or `9.41E+20`?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook  You are correct...see my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @Buckethead  thank you for the feedback....but be aware that you will get what you see in the cell rather than what you see in the *Formula Bar*.

Comment: Now try that with `941144280284022000001`

Comment: @TimWilliams Just getting your string in a cell requires the cell to be formatted as ***Text*** or to place a single quote before the ***9***

Comment: That was my point I guess - how the values are entered is the main issue here.

Comment: @TimWilliams My answer assumed that the issue of getting the numeral string into the cell had already been resolved and that cell displayed the numeral string quoted in the question.

Comment: I just thought it was worth including explicitly in your answer: the comment about displaying as #### or 9.41E+20 would only happen with a non-text entry.

Comment: @TimWilliams  Is my **EDIT** any better ??

Answer (score 2):

Try a simple :

```
Dim myVar as Variant

myVar = CDec(Range("A1").Value)
```

Comment: Now try that with `941144280284022000001`

Comment: `? CDec(941144280284022000001)` >> `941144280284022000000`

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to store a value that *looks* like a number (or is a number) but has more than 15 digits of precision, then you *must* either format the cell as text *before* entering the value, or prepend the value with a single apostrophe to indicate to Excel that the value is to be treated as text and not a number.

If you *don't* do this, then as soon as the value is entered, there's a good chance it will be altered by Excel. The trailing zeros in the example value mean this does not happen in this specific case, but try changing that last 0 to 1 and you'll see what I mean.

You enter: 941144280284022000001

Excel converts this to: 94114428028402200000**0**

More reading:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel