# Determining if a string has been entered with a leading single quote

Tags: excel, vba

This question arose in my attempt to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48421941/4996248):

In a blank workbook, format `A1:A2` as text. In `A1` type `123` and in A2 type `'123`. Both result in the string `"123"` being the cell value:

[image]

But -- the *formula bar* displays the text `'123` when `A2` is selected but only displays `123` when `A1` is selected, so Excel retains the information about how the strings were entered. Can this information be accessed from VBA?

A quick test which shows what *doesn't* work:

```
Sub test()
    Dim R As Range, S As Range
    Set R = Range("A1")
    Set S = Range("A2")
    Debug.Print R.Value = S.Value
    Debug.Print R.Value2 = S.Value2
    Debug.Print R.Text = S.Text
    Debug.Print R.Formula = S.Formula
    Debug.Print R.FormulaLocal = S.FormulaLocal
    Debug.Print R.FormulaR1C1 = S.FormulaR1C1
    Debug.Print R.FormulaR1C1Local = S.FormulaR1C1Local
End Sub
```

This does nothing but repeatedly print `True`. I can't think of any other range properties that would be relevant. I don't see any application or worksheet level object which allows one to access the text displayed in the formula bar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `PrefixCharacter` property of `Range` to access the apostrophe.

```
Debug.Print [A1].PrefixCharacter ' prints blank line
Debug.Print [A2].PrefixCharacter ' prints apostrophe
```

Comment: That was easy. I attempted to use the `Characters` property but couldn't successfully call it on those cells (since those strings don't support RTF?) so I overlooked the other properties involving characters. I'll accept this when the requisite time has elapsed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Sub SingleQuoteTest()
    MsgBox ActiveCell.PrefixCharacter = "'"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer (+1)  but the other answer was first by about 10 seconds. There is still a potentially interesting question about how to programmatically access the displayed string in the formula bar.

Comment: @JohnColeman  I have never attempted to get the Formula Bar as a text string.

Comment: It was actually your comment to this question that got me wondering about that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41596316/4996248